# Getting count() of an SOQL as zero

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test

I have one test class.I have soql inside which gives me count() of opportunity.I am getting count of opportunity as zero.WHile i have added 2 opportunity inside the test class.Please let me know where am i doing wrong.Value of dummy for debug log is zero.

Test class :

```
@isTest
public class Pagination_Test {
    static testMethod void testUnitTestOne(){
        Test.startTest();
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name='wbstest21';
        insert acc;
        List<Opportunity> opps = new List<Opportunity>();
        System.debug('value of account id ::::: '+acc.id);
        Opportunity o1 = new Opportunity(AccountId=acc.id, Name='ABC', stageName='Prospecting', CloseDate=Date.today());
        Opportunity o2 = new Opportunity(AccountId=acc.id, Name='XYZ', stageName='Prospecting', CloseDate=Date.today());
        opps.add(o1);
        opps.add(o2);
        System.debug('Value of Opportunities :::: '+opps);
        Integer dummy = [select count() from Opportunity where stageName NOT IN ('Closed Won','Closed Lost')];

        System.debug('Value of dummy :::: '+dummy);

        Pagination page = new Pagination();
        page.getOpplist();

        System.debug('Value of getopp :::: '+page.getOpplist());
        Test.stopTest();
    }

}
```

Comment: First insert the `opps` list, then perform the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue: You are performing SOQL without DML statement.

Solution: update code as shown below

```
@isTest
public class Pagination_Test {
static testMethod void testUnitTestOne(){
    Test.startTest();
    Account acc = new Account();
    acc.Name='wbstest21';
    insert acc;
    List<Opportunity> opps = new List<Opportunity>();
    System.debug('value of account id ::::: '+acc.id);
    Opportunity o1 = new Opportunity(AccountId=acc.id, Name='ABC', stageName='Prospecting', CloseDate=Date.today());
    Opportunity o2 = new Opportunity(AccountId=acc.id, Name='XYZ', stageName='Prospecting', CloseDate=Date.today());
    opps.add(o1);
    opps.add(o2);
    insert opps; /* Inserting opportunity */
    System.debug('Value of Opportunities :::: '+opps);
    Integer dummy = [select count() from Opportunity where stageName NOT IN ('Closed Won','Closed Lost')];

    System.debug('Value of dummy :::: '+dummy);

    Pagination page = new Pagination();
    page.getOpplist();

    System.debug('Value of getopp :::: '+page.getOpplist());
    Test.stopTest();
}

}
```